# NIFI: Unable to extract values from JSON

Tags: apache-nifi

Initially i am querying a table to get two values id,payload. The payload field is again a json but in a string. please check below payload string.

```
{
  "schema": "http://schemas.viacom.com/what/is/the/path#",
  "op": "delete",
  "entity": "movie",
  "entity_identifier": {
    "series_code": 53709,
    "episode_code": 1
  },
  "entity_vmid": "",
  "short_name": "",
  "title": ""
}
```

I want series_code and episode_code values. I Tried in below ways but of no use

1. ExecuteSQL --> ConvertAvrotoJSON --> EvaluateJSON($.payload.entity_identifier.series_code)
2. ExecuteSQL --> ConvertAvrotoJSON --> AttributestoJSON --> EvaluateJSON

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`EvaluateJsonPath`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) processor to evaluate [JsonPath](http://jsonpath.com/) expressions against the content of the flowfile. You add one user-defined property per value you want to extract. Set the `Destination` value to `flowfile-attribute` to extract the value into an attribute which will be added to the flowfile, or `flowfile-content` to generate a new flowfile with the extracted value as the sole content.

Given the JSON you provided, the two path expressions you would use are:

- `$.entity_identifier.series_code` -> `53709`
- `$.entity_identifier.episode_code` -> `1`